# I'm trying to install an Operating System

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I am currently running Windows 7 on a Dell Inspiron R17 N7110, and I'd like to run Ubuntu alongside Windows.

I need to shrink the Windows partition somehow so that I can install Ubuntu. Currently, when trying to resize the partition within Ubuntu, Ubuntu wants to format the Windows partition to ext4.

When I try to shrink it in GParted, I hit the maximum **and** minimum partition size, which just so happens to be the HDD size and the HDD size minus one MiB, respectively.

When I try to shrink it in Windows, it tells me I can't shrink it because it is in use.

I have already spoken with people at AskUbuntu, and they have redirected me here.

Thanks in advance.

Post from AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158702/one-last-thing-before-i-install

Comment: How exactly are you trying to shrink it in Windows?

Comment: Disk Manager, Disk management, something like that. I access it at `Control Panel\Administrative tools\Computer Management\Disk Management`

Comment: OK, it should be possible to do it from there and it usually doesn't complain about being in use. Have you at some point enabled the dynamic volumes feature? If so that's a problem.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: In disk management it should show "basic" or "dynamic" in the partitions.

Comment: Ok, is there any way for me to tell from Ubuntu? I'm running a live session right now, and I'd rather not leave it unless I have to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96261/discussion-between-cstafford-14-and-gabrielagarcia).

Comment: Yes, there's a way to tell from Ubuntu. Open GParted and check the drive. If you see the partitions as they show up in Windows, you're fine (basic), if you don't then their "dynamic" and that's a problem.

Comment: Just a heads up for when you get past partition resizing... be careful about assuming your system is using MBR booting. It may use EFI instead. I've seen a lot of people who had minor dual-booting issues follow some guide from 15 years ago that ignores the existence of EFI and ended up corrupting their whole hard drive. Or even people on this very site who assume all computers boot via MBR giving bad advice as a result. Make sure you know which you have. Google will help with this. And if you don't have backups... make them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows 7, install Minitool Partition Wizard : https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Then shrink/split from there.

Comment: The question should probably have been asked on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) - and this is exactly the answer it would have gotten there (+1). There's simply nothing to compare at the price (free).

Comment: I used the windows partitioner, and it did the same job. Since it was a partition issue, you get the accepted tick! Thanks for your answer!